# STL syntax, container with reference to pointer

Tags: c++, stl

i want to create a container which contains references to pointers

1) Is this possible?

2) What is the syntax?

I imagine its

```
<T*&>
```

ie:
    std::stack< int*& > stack_;

but this just gives me errors "xmemory: pointer to reference is illegal."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use references as the element type of a container, because there is no such thing as a reference object in C++.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why not simply use a `std::stack<int>`?

Comment: I want a stack of pointers. When the pointers in the stack are modified, the original pointer that was passed into the stack should be modified too.

I guess the solution is to use a stack of pointers to pointers.

Comment: Pointer to pointers are hardly ever the right solution... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `std::stack<int*>`? What advantages do you see in using references to pointers? Or maybe, just `std::stack<int>` should suffice your need? Have you tried them?